# How do you show the value of a select form using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<select id="testlist" class="select-block span8">
    <option value="0">Red</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Yellow</option>
    <option value="2">Blue</option>
    <option value="3">Green</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

When selected, I want the div "result" to automatically update to show the value of the selected option. For example, if I selected Blue, I would want the div to show "2".

I've tried:

```
<script>$('#testlist').val()</script>
```

with no luck

Using jQuery (or javascript if that's more sensible), how would I do this?

Comment: `$('#testlist').val()`

Comment: The [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change): `$("#selectlist").change(function() { alert($(this).val()) })`

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Showing an effort of things you've already tried usually gets you better answers here.

Comment: @Jason My initial attempts were to just directly use `<script>$('#testlist').val()</script>` - which is evidently wrong.

I then had a look for something similar to a PHP echo, which seems to be document.write(). However, I don't think that's what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work fine:

```
//when the select changes
$('#testlist').on('change', function() {
    //set the text to the select's value
    $('#result').text($(this).val());
}
```

Depending on if your div has `result` as it's ID. You can see a working jsFiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/MQBJ6/

Comment: I'm a complete newbie at jQuery - how would I implement that?

`<script>//when the select changes
$('#biomelist').on('change', function() {
    //set the text to the select's value
    $('#result').text($(this).val());
}</script>

<select id="testlist" class="select-block span8">
        <option value="0">Red</option>
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Yellow</option>
        <option value="2">Blue</option>
        <option value="3">Green</option>
      </select>
   <div id="result"></div>
`
This code doesn't seem to cause the div to edit.

Comment: Make sure you run your code in the dom ready event. Edited answer with a working link.

Answer (score 0):

@Chad's answer will work with jQuery - if you're not using jQuery you could always go with:

```
<select id="testlist" class="select-block span8" onChange="setDiv();">
    <option value="0">Red</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Yellow</option>
    <option value="2">Blue</option>
    <option value="3">Green</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    function setDiv(){
        var testlist = document.getElementById('testlist').value;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = testlist;
    }
</script>
```

See jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jreljac/amara/

Comment: I assumed he was since the question was tagged `jquery`